# itextpdf 7: unable to sign existing PDF (SigDict /Contents illegal data)

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a PDF certified by a third-party.

I would like to sign it with iText PDF (version 7).

I've taken an example from [here](https://itextpdf.com/en/solutions/electronic-signatures-pdf) and slightly modified. Here is what I have at the moment:

```java
package src.main.java.app;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.StampingProperties;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.BouncyCastleDigest;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.DigestAlgorithms;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.IExternalDigest;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.IExternalSignature;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSignatureAppearance;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSigner;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.PrivateKeySignature;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class Sign {
    public static final String DEST = "/app/storage/";

    public static final String KEYSTORE = "/app/storage/my.p12";
    public static final String SRC = "/app/storage/unsigned.pdf";

    public static final char[] PASSWORD = "secret-password".toCharArray();

    public static final String[] RESULT_FILES = new String[] {
            "hello_signed1.pdf",
            "hello_signed2.pdf",
            "hello_signed3.pdf",
            "hello_signed4.pdf"
    };

    public void sign(String src, String dest, Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm,
                     String provider, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard signatureType, String reason, String location)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), new StampingProperties());

        // Create the signature appearance
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 648, 200, 100);
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance
                .setReason(reason)
                .setLocation(location)

                // Specify if the appearance before field is signed will be used
                // as a background for the signed field. The "false" value is the default value.
                .setReuseAppearance(false)
                .setPageRect(rect)
                .setPageNumber(1);
        signer.setFieldName("SignatureField[0]");

        IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
        IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

        // Sign the document using the detached mode, CMS or CAdES equivalent.
        signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, signatureType);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.mkdirs();

        BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(provider);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE), PASSWORD);
        String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, PASSWORD);
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);

        Sign app = new Sign();
        app.sign(SRC, DEST + RESULT_FILES[0], chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName(),
                PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test 1", "Ghent");
        app.sign(SRC, DEST + RESULT_FILES[1], chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA512, provider.getName(),
                PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test 2", "Ghent");
        app.sign(SRC, DEST + RESULT_FILES[2], chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName(),
                PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES, "Test 3", "Ghent");
        app.sign(SRC, DEST + RESULT_FILES[3], chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.RIPEMD160, provider.getName(),
                PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES, "Test 4", "Ghent");
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot from Adobe for `unsigned.pdf`, for me it shows a valid signature:

[image: Unsigned PDF]

Once it is signed (if I open any of `hello_signed*.pdf` PDFs), I see the following picture:

[image: Signed PDF result]

First signature seems to be broken ("SigDict /Contents illegal data") and it didn't set the field name correctly. I assume that's because I need to put full path to `SignatureField1` as following `root[0].containerpage[0].footer[0].SignatureField1[0]`. However, it is not possible, because `PdfSigner.setField` method does not support `.` in the name.

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

By the way, running `SignatureUtil` shows unsigned field correctly, but with the full path with `.`:

```java
//...
PdfDocument pdfDocument = signer.getDocument();
SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);
PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, false);

for (String name : signatureUtil.getBlankSignatureNames()) {
    System.out.println(field.getFieldName());
}
// Outputs:
// root[0].containerpage[0].footer[0].SignatureField1[0]
```

Just in case, here are my dependencies:

Dependencies I have (pom file):

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>sign</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.68</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Consider using the `StampingProperties` to select append mode. Without append mode you damage previous signatures.

Comment: @mkl `StampingProperties.useAppendMode` helped, thanks a lot!

Comment: @mkl Do you know anything about issue where field name has dots and it is impossible to set it via  `PdfSigner.setField`? When I set `root[0].containerpage[0].footer[0].SignatureField1[0]` it doesn't like dots, when I set `SignatureField1` or `SignatureField1[0]`, Adobe does not recognize field as signed. Do you have any experience on this?

Comment: Currently iText 7 does not support names with dots in `setFieldName`. Most likely this is so because it does not create a field hierarchy but merely a single field when *creating* a new field. In a case like yours, though, in which the field already exists, there likely would be no problem if one allowed dots in `setFieldName`.

Comment: @mkl is there a way to set existing field with dots?

Comment: I'm afraid not without patching the iText code itself.